# Use scrollbars for the display of a continous form in Microsoft Access2007

Tags: scrollbar, ms-access-2007, continuous-forms

I have a continuous form with many control elements ordered in two columns. The form is opened with the WindowMode 'acDialog'.

When I take a look at this form at my desktop computer there is no problem. But I want to use the application also on my laptop. When I open the form on my laptop, I only see the first entries, but not the others anymore. Unfortunately I havent found an opportunity to use scrollbars in my form.

What I have found is this (did not work):
[Add or remove scrollbars](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-or-remove-scroll-bars-HP005187903.aspx)

Edit:
The View should look like:
[image: Right view]

but on my laptop it looks like:
[image: False view]

So I want to have scrollbars. The scrollbar property is set to both directions.

Edit 20121126, the design view. The blue part is header, the txts are in the detail view and the buttons are in the footer:
[image: design view]

Comment: I'm guessing the screen resolution on your laptop is set differently to that of the desktop? Something to bear in mind when creating forms, having said that adding scroll bars shouldn't be a problem, are you using the same version of Access on both machines?

Comment: That is the point. The resolution on my desktop is much higher. That is why the view is cut off. On both machines I use Access 2007

Comment: Why are you trying to add scrollbars to textboxes? I think at this stage a picture would help.

Comment: Please read the text correctly. I do not want to add scrollbars to textboxes, but to the continuous form. I want the form to be viewed correctly, when the solution of the screen changes to a smaller one.

Comment: @Hauke As Remou suggested a picture may be of value, as the link you provided in the question should hold the solution, difficult to understand why it's not working in your case without seeing it. Are you using a sub-form perhaps, have you set the scrollbar properties on the correct form?

Comment: See the edited entry. I do not use a sub form.

Comment: @Hauke Are the **Data Today** and **Data Tmrw** headers in the **Header** section of the form, the main fields in the **Detail** section, and the buttons in the **Footer** section. That may be what's required to force the scroll bars, are you able to post a pic of the form in design view please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has stumped me before.  Access is not smart enough to realize if the screen is set to a different 'zoom' than 100%.  So Access is thinking that the entire form is on your screen when really it is not.

This really only applies if you have Windows 7 and maybe 8, but I have no idea about that.  If you go to your display property (right click the desktop and select 'Personalize' then Display in the lower left-hand corner of the pop-up.)

If you are not set at 100% then access is missing 25-50% of your screen.  access goes off of pixels, which is set in the resloution, but when using 125% Windows expands everything by 25% and that can push things right off the screen.  The form does not need scroll bars to fit on your screen, just need to set your zoom to 100%.

I found this out by having a 'control bar' set to be x-250 pixels from the left (where x is total left to right pixels).  However one computer could never see the control bar and it was because the screen was +125%. I have never been able to figure out how to get the current 'zoom' from Windows.  I have searched through all manner of API's.  I hope this is the solution you were looking for!  Good Luck!!

Comment: Unfortunately that wasnt the problem in my case. But how should someone get solutions for this stuff?

Comment: Sorry, I was sure that was your problem.  What if you change the size of your form On_Load?  Use some code like this...
`DoCmd.MoveSize W, X, Y, Z`
You can leave W and X blank, they move the screen from the left and the toprespectively, but leaving them blank will center the form.  Also, leave the Y blank as horizontal scrolling isn't your issue.  Set Z to a number smaller than your actual form.  Get this number by multiplying your form height in inches by 1440.  Then just subtract 2000 or so and see if your scroll bars appear.  They should be there on both screens.  Let me know!